# recursive wget control download

Tags: download, wget

The recursive option of wget (`-r` option) occasionally yields many files. For example,`wget -r www.cnn.com` gives the following:

```
--2013-05-05 10:35:54--  http://www.cnn.com/about/
Reusing existing connection to www.cnn.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘www.cnn.com/about/index.html’

--2013-05-05 10:35:54--  http://www.cnn.com/help/
Reusing existing connection to www.cnn.com:80.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘www.cnn.com/help/index.html’

......
```

How can this be controlled - can we to specify the maximum total size of download, the maximum time of download, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

To stop a command after a certain time you can use the command `timeout`.

```
timeout 60 wget ...
```

will stop the download after 60 seconds.

You can add an optional unit after the duration:

- 's' for seconds (default)
- 'm' for minutes
- 'h' for hours
- 'd' for days